Proof that Inverse CDH and Square CDH are equivalent
I am trying to prove said equivalence, but when proving SCDH -> ICDH using a reduction, I get stuck since I don't know how to compute $g^{x^2}$ starting from $g^{x^{-1}}$.
Suppose exists $A_{ICDH}$ that can solve Inverse CDH, we can use it to build $A_{SCDH}$ that breaks Square CDH.
Let $C_{SCDH}$ be the challenger for Square CDH.
$C_{SCDH}$ will:

sample $x \leftarrow \\\$ \mathcal{Z}^*_q$;
run $groupGen(1^{\lambda})$ obtaining $params$ = $(\mathcal{G},g,q)$;
send $g^x$,$params$ to $A_{SCDH}$;

$A_{SCDH}$ can now send $params$, $g^x$ to $A_{ICDH}$, obtaining $g^{x^{-1}}$.
Here's where I am stuck. How can $A_{SCDH}$ compute $g^{x^2}$?

There's already a similar question on the forum. If you want a hint before checking the solution: observe that you are constrained to additions, subtraction and computing inverses (modulo $q$). So can you combine these somehow to compute $x^2$ given only $x$? See the solution here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/111861/58690
